Problem regarding False discovery rate correction for multiple comparison
I am conducting research to find association of a gene with a disease. It's a case-control study. I have divided the cases into groups A and B based on genotype and controls into groups C and D. I would like to compare the mean of 20 different parameters between A and B using unpaired t-test. I will compare the same 20 parameters between group C and D.
During FDR correction, will I have to rank 40 p-values at the same time? Or do I need adjust separately for 20 p-values between group A and B, and then 20 p-values between group C and D?

If you want to control the false positive rate of the whole study, you should correct for the total number of comparisons in the study.

Suppose you would have óne parameter only for the cases and the controls, so a total of two tests. Would you then want to correct for false discovery?
